# How to convert string of numbers ( '14, 72' ) to numbers in sql query

Tags: sql

```
 declare @lkaklf as varchar(Max)
 Select ss.Data from SplitString('14,72', ',') as ss

 Select @lkaklf = CONVERT(varchar, COALESCE( + @lkaklf + ',', '') + '''' + Data + '''') From
 (
    Select Data from SplitString('14,72', ',') 
 )de
 select @lkaklf
 print @lkaklf
 Select * from LPO Where CONVERT(varchar, LPO.LocalPurchaseOrderId) in (@lkaklf)
```

@lkalf value is Printing in message but not coming into select query... Why ?

Comment: Any SQL dialect in particular?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want.  I would recommend that you skip over the splitting part of the query and just do:

```
where ','+@lkaklf+',' like ','+cast(LPO.LocalPurchaseOrderId as varchar(255))+',%'
```

That is, just use string comparisons.

If you *really* want to use `SplitString()`, then put the results in a temporary table:

```
insert into @t
    select data from splitstring('14,72', ',')
```

And then use a subquery:

```
where cast(@lkalklf as varchar(255)) in (select data from @t)
```